# How to broadcast time-synchronized text streams using IIS Smooth Streaming?

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, smooth-streaming-player, smooth-streaming

I'm studying the feasibility of using IIS Smooth Streaming to build a rich web application to display time synchronized audio/video and related textual data. The text data is a set of spacecraft telemetry that should be displayed outside of the video window.

I've seen [some examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336025.aspx) of how to display video captions at the correct time using this technology. I've also read Chapter 11 of Silverlight Recipes 2nd edition which again shows video captions. What I'm trying to do is a little bit more complex - show numerous pieces of data outside of the video window. The data should be in sync with the video playhead at all times.

It looks like I will encode my text data in tracks using the StreamIndex element type, with Type="text" and SubType="data". On the client, how do I display this in a separate panel next to the video?

From the marketese I know IIS Smooth Streaming must handle this scenario. I'm just having no luck finding examples of how to handle the data on the client side. Can someone point me to an example, or tell me why this is not possible?